# Call function t/s with "ease out" effect

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

This is more of a math question I guess but if anyone can help me define how to write the code it would be great!

The goal is to call a function repeatedly at a set time interval. But the calls-per-second interval needs to be calculated so that it follows an ease-out curve.

So I want the player to input a number to a variable lets call it X.

- X * Time.deltaTime should give me a call-per-second.
- The higher number given to X the faster call-per-second result.
- The higher the value of X gets smaller effect it has on the call-per-second interval.

Math isn't my strong side so if anyone can help me defining this code it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a use case for `log`

Comment: Depends on how you want to scale it. Logarthimic scaling is one possibility where a value can still approximate infinity. If you want it to cap out at a certain value a `value - 1/x` might do the trick, just avoid a division by zero.

Comment: I don't get the third point

Comment: @NikaKasradze so X should affect the call-per-second interval less the higher the value of X is.

Comment: @Rob I tried callPerSec = Mathf.Log10(x); but it goes in the wrong direction. The high X is the slower call per second rate. Any idea of how to flip it?

Answer (score 0):

well you could use AnimationCurve for this one

```
public AnimationCurve callPerSecondCurve;

//this is x value on animation curve
public float yourXvar;

void Start(){
    yourXvar = Mathf.Clamp(yourXvar, 0f, 10f); //so that you don't go out of curve range
    CallerFunction();
}

void CallerFunction(){
    float frequency = callPerSecondCurve.Evaluate(yourXvar);

    //exit condition
    if(frequency < 0.01f)
        return;

    float waitTime = 1f / callPerSecondCurve.Evaluate(yourXvar);
    Invoke("CallerFunction", waitTime);
    yourXvar -= waitTime;
    Debug.Log("Bam");

    //call your target function() HERE
}
```

Set the animation curve to something like

[image: Call frequency curve]

Basically what should happen is after you input the **yourXvar** in the inspector and press play the CallerFunction() should get called in decreasing frequency.

Comment: Ok, I don't really know how to use these animation curves. I've never done it before. But as I asked Rob, I tried the Log approach and got the result I wanted only in the wrong direction :P
I tried callPerSec = Mathf.Log10(x); but the higher X value the slower callPerSec ratio so do you know how to flip that?